# Hidden WebRTC getUserMedia Stream in Safari 16

Tags: safari, webrtc

I called getUserMedia and stop all tracks in Safari 16, the red camera icon disappears and the camera light is off but both come back again. Is there a way to track getUserMedia calls in Safari like in Chrome internals? I try to find a hidden stream. Any help would be appreciated.